# Blackberry & SPF

Tags: email, spam, blackberry, spf

Some users on my domain use a Blackberry for email.  Should Blackberry's servers be included somehow in my SPF record?

Thank you much for any advice.

Comment: Do you use BES or BIS for the Blackberries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should be all set. Assuming you are using BES locally, the mail ultimately flows through your (Exchange?) server, and as long as the IP for that server is included in your SPF, you are good to go.

Comment: BIS uses its own SMTP servers, therefore it's required to add them to your own records for SPF to work properly. This answer is incomplete at best if not flat-out wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to include all IP addresses that are authorised to send email using your domain (you can list the MX records if these are also your outgoing SMTP servers).

I don't know about the blackberry service, but doesn't it just use your own exchange server to send? Try sending a test email from the blackberry and check the email headers for the IP addresses in the Received lines?

Comment: BIS does not use your own SMTP server, it does instead route outgoing email through its own SMTP servers.

Comment: you're answer is too general, specific questions should have specific answers.